# Ionic2 select text in ion-searchbar

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, searchbar

In an ion-input focus event we can select all the text like this

```
<ion-input (focus)="selectAll($event)></ion-input>
```

But in an ion-searchbar it does not work:

```
<ion-searchbar (focus)="selectAll($event)></ion-searchbar>
```

The selectAll() code would be:

```
public selectAll(event): void {
    event.target.select();
}
```

I have seen in ionic's Github that the input component returns a FocusEvent:

```
inputFocused(event) {
  this.focus.emit(event);
}
```

On the other hand the ion-searchbar returns a searchbar (this):

```
inputFocused() {
  this.focus.emit(this);

  this.isFocused = true;
  this.shouldLeftAlign = true;
  this.setElementLeft();
}
```

Why does it not return a FocusEvent too? How can we select all the text in an ion-searchbar when it is focused?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ion-searchbar is more than just an input element. Therefore you need to grab the inputElement attribute instead of the target:

```
public selectAll(event): void {
    event.inputElement.select();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for **ion-searchbar** to use:

```
<ion-searchbar click="selectAll($event)"></ion-searchbar>

selectAll(event){
   event.target.select();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, but use `$event.srcElement.select();` instead!

Comment: This may answer a question. but please describe it little more.